# wordpress query - orderby child post date

Tags: query, order

I have support ticket system which i have built using wordpress.

The basic functionality is that when a "ticket" is created, it creates a post. When an admin replies, it then add a child post to the original post.

My question is how can i order my posts by the child post_date is ASC order?

My query args at the moment are:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'support_tickets',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_parent' => 0,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC'  );
```

This only obviously orders the parent post's in ASC by date. Is what i require achievable?

Comment: I imagine that you could get this to work with enough effort, but I am not sure you could get it to work efficiently. You are talking about a lot of tricky SQL and/or PHP manipulation of the data. I would suggest that your design is going to cause you a lot of pain. Use comments, or a custom built table/interface.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes i did imagine it would be a lot of work and headache... i will spend some more time looking into it, and if no joy i will go down the route of using comments or another custom solution

Comment: What solution did you land on?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the `get_children` function (see the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)),

```
$ticket_id = 34; // assume you want to retried the replies of ticket post id=34
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'support_tickets',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_parent' => $ticket_id,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC'  );
$replies = get_children( $args );
```

Assuming that your custom post `support_tickets` has been registered with the attribute `hierarchical` set to true (see [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#hierarchical)).